# String.matches() return false unexpectedly.

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to write a program that interprets race results. However in order to do this I need to use regex to test if strings match a certain pattern using the `String.matches(String regex)` method.
When using this methods some strings that I expect to return `true`, return `false` instead.

Using the following string as the regex pattern, some of the strings return `true` and other `false` when the should return `true` as well:

```
regex = "[ ]*[1-9]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[1-9]+[ ]+[1-9]+[ ]+[0-9:.]+[ ]+"
```

These are some of the strings that return `true` with the `string.matches(String regex)` method:

```
" 1 Ryan Kepshire Crown Point 31 4 16:31 "
" 2 Matthew Mosak Crown Point 34 4 16:44 "
" 3 Dylan Wallace Crown Point 36 4 16:58 "
" 4 Nicholas Zak Hanover Central 51 6 17:08 "
" 5 Joshua Whitaker Crown Point 37 4 17:16 "
" 8 Collin Allen Hobart 64 8 17:23 "
" 9 Zachary Hoover Crown Point 29 4 17:29 "
```

These are some of the strings that return `false` with the `string.matches(String regex)` method:

```
" 6 Christopher Ramos River Forest 103 12 17:18 "
" 7 Boyer Hunter Lowell 78 10 17:20 "
" 10 Miguel Tapia Merrillville 98 11 17:32 "
```

I need help with determining why the bottom three strings fail the regex test while the top 7 pass it.

Comment: You just need to change your character classes from `[1-9]` to be `[0-9]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]+[a-zA-Z]+[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ 
     ^ 
]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[a-zA-Z]*[ ]?[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9]+[ ]+[0-9:.]+[ ]+
                             ^         ^
```

Your regex does not allow `0` in integers.That is why it was failing.See here.

http://regex101.com/r/uH3tP3/5

I have modified it to accept `0`.

Ex. `[1-9]+` will not accept `10`.

" 6 Christopher Ramos River Forest `103` 12 17:18 "             //fails due to `103`

" 7 Boyer Hunter Lowell 78 `10` 17:20 "                         //fails due to `10`

" `10` Miguel Tapia Merrillville 98 11 17:32                    //fails due to `10`

Comment: Thanks for seeing that. I can't believe I missed that. Also I had never seen regex101.com. It is a nice resource.